# insertion-sort on doubly linked list

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is an attempt to write an insertion-sort function for a doubly linked list (DLL). It is modelled on [insertion-sort as known for arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm). I get a `NullPointerException`. why?

before sorting, the list looks like this: `aaa zzz Ciao Salut Hi Hello`

```
public static DLL sort(DLL list)
{
    DLLNode ptr2 = list.first.succ ;

    while (ptr2 != null)
    {
        DLLNode ptr1 = ptr2.pred ;
        String curr = ptr2.elem ;

        while (ptr1 != list.first && curr.compareToIgnoreCase(ptr1.elem) < 0)
        {
            ptr1.succ.elem = ptr1.elem ;
            ptr1 = ptr1.pred ;
        }
        ptr1.succ.elem = curr ;

        ptr2 = ptr2.succ ;
    }

    return list ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try printing your list backwards, to be sure that all your `node.pred` are not null.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  a debugger or the good old `System.out.println` method.

Places to look:

- `curr` before `curr.compareTo...`
- `ptr1.succ` before `ptr1.succ.elem = ...`
- `ptr2` before `ptr2.succ`
- `ptr1` before `ptr1.elem`

But your exception tells you where the exception originated